# Using robot framework operating system library

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to use the RF library "OperatingSystem".
found at this link:
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.8.7/libraries/OperatingSystem.html

I try with pip

pip install robotframework-operatingsystem

but it says it cannot find it. Also in PyCharm/Settings/python intepreter it does not show up in the list of available packages.
Maybe it is because it was connected to an old version of robot framework. If that is the case, can you point to an existing library that does the same things?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OperatingSystem library is part of Robot Framework's standard library, eg, it is shipped with robotframework and does not need to be installed.

Only thing you need to do to use OperatingSystem is to load it in your settings section with like

```
*** Settings ***
Library   OperatingSystem
```

And the rest is up to you and your pycharm ..

Comment: Ah, of course, I had it but did not have the tab in between the two terms. Thanks!

Comment: @AnnaRamolini Please accept the answer by using the tick mark next to it. :)